# How can I identify the particular attachments when I click on a button in cards?

Tags: bots, botframework

I am working on a bot project. How can I implement a feature like this?

[image]

Here when I click the Show Me button of Search Flights its providing flights related information and when I am click the show me button of Search Hotel its providing the hotel related information.

In my current working bot when I am click reserve now(like in the above figure show me button) I am getting the JSON response without information of selected attachment like this below figure.

[image]

So, how can I do the same thing in my bot?

For that I am write the below lines of code in my Project

```
enter code here
  place=activity.text(with in the place i am passing the city name)
               MessagesController.hotelsList = await       PropertyService.getHotelsList(place, DateTime.Now);
            var hotellist = MessagesController.hotelsList;
            Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Welcome to **Hotel Reservation Bot**." + "(Hi)");
            replyToConversation.Recipient = message.From;
            replyToConversation.Type = "message";
            replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

            foreach (var list in hotellist.SearchResults)
            {

                List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
                CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
                {
                    Value ="Reserve Now",
                    Type = "imBack",
                    Title = "Reserve Now"
                };
                cardButtons.Add(plButton);
                ThumbnailCard plCard = new ThumbnailCard()
                {
                    Title = i + "." + "Name:" + list.Property.CallingDisplayName,
                    Subtitle = "Location:" + list.Property.Location.City,
                    Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons
                };
                        Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
                        i++;

            }
            replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you'd show your code, but the general idea is that the text on the button and what that button actually sends to the chat must be different:

```
var button = new CardAction() {
    Title = "Show me",
    Value = "Show restaurant #" + restaurantID,
    Type = ActionTypes.imBack
};
```

When the user clicks it, they will see `"Show me"` in chat, but actually your application will receive `"Show restaurant #35"` in `Activity.Text`.

Comment: hi @k48 I am added the code in my above question please go through their

Comment: So just change Value ="Reserve Now" into the actual value that you need to pass? E.g. the ID.

Comment: Actually, in C# the Value is what is being sent to the chat.

Comment: We are also did the same thing like what you said in above but I think this is not a good procedure to do that

Comment: I am also did the same like what ever the value assigning that is being displaying in chat